# Is there a more complete description of Java code generated by Thrift than in "Thrift: The Missing Guide"?

Tags: thrift

I was looking for a description of Thrift Java code generation similar to [the one for Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated). But the best I could find was http://diwakergupta.github.com/thrift-missing-guide/#_java, which is quite old (e.g. before unions were added) and not detailed. Is there such a description somewhere, or is my best option to look at Thrift tests?

Comment: +1 for asking the question even I have.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what you are looking for exactly, even with the protobuf document at hand. The Whitepaper is (at least for now) the most basic documentation, plus Diwaker Gupta's guide, which you already found.

Do you want to learn more about how it is working internally? Then, yes at this time the best way is to use the Tutorials, maybe grasp a Debugger and follow the execution paths.

Do you want to learn about how to get the generated code to work? Same here, have a look at the Tutorial and the Test Server/Test Client pair.

You are just curious what is possible with Thrift? Well, there are a number of test cases and other IDL files in the source paths, which help to understand the possibilities of the IDL.

Last not least, you are free to ask specific questions in the mailing list.